# Как получить тип тега source в html5 video на YouTube?

Tags: html5, видео, youtube

Мне надо достать type (например video/webm) html5 видео на Ютубе, но внутри тега нет source. Метод `canPlayType` не совсем то, что надо. С помощью `getAttribute` получается доставать, если только присутствует явно, но внутри тега video только src.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 1):

Пользуйтесь уже имеющимся кодом для скачивания видео с тытрубки, всё реализовано до вас. Если очень хочется делать всё ручками, то разбирайте код жабоскрипта, в котором и содержатся интересующие вас данные. Например, на [первой попавшейся странице](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7PQ9IO-7fU) с плеером HTML5 на YouTube в коде можно заметить:

`var ytplayer = ytplayer || {};ytplayer.config = {"assets":{"css":"\/\/s.ytimg.com\/yts\/cssbin\/www-player-new-vflgEPPga.css","js":"\/\/s.ytimg.com\/yts\/jsbin\/html5player-new-en_US-vflx6L8FI\/html5player-new.js"},"url_v8":"http:\/\/s.ytimg.com\/yts\/swfbin\/player-vflbGGFmi\/cps.swf","sts":16735,"url_v9as2":"http:\/\/s.ytimg.com\/yts\/swfbin\/player-vflbGGFmi\/cps.swf","messages":{"player_fallback":["Adobe Flash Player or an HTML5 supported browser is required for video playback.\u003cbr\u003e\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/get.adobe.com\/flashplayer\/\"\u003eGet the latest Flash Player \u003c\/a\u003e\u003cbr\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/html5\"\u003eLearn more about upgrading to an HTML5 browser\u003c\/a\u003e"]},"params":{"allowfullscreen":"true","allowscriptaccess":"always","bgcolor":"#000000"},"args":{"timestamp":"1445985086","sffb":true,"allow_embed":"1","user_gender":"m","author":"WarpOut","iurlsd":"http:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/i7PQ9IO-7fU\/sddefault.jpg","no_get_video_log":"1","c":"WEB","adaptive_fmts":"size=1920x1080\u0026index=713-1704\u0026projection_type=1\u0026fps=24\u0026bitrate=4128390\u0026clen=107453625\u0026type=video%2Fmp4%3B+codecs%3D%22avc1.640028%22\u0026init=0-712\u0026itag=137\u0026quality_label=1080p\u0026lmt=1441184970413183\u0026url=http%3A%2F%2Fr1---sn-xguxaxjvh-31oe.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fsver%3D3%26dur%3D422.374%26signature%3D9202C41B0CF8FBCE3A166A225DAB659D8BEC6E2E.D737FDB504459C256588D897BD513B959920C3E8%26initcwndbps%3D3415000%26cwbhb%3Dyes%26keepalive%3Dyes%26clen%3D107453625%26itag%3D137%26ipbits%3D0%26upn%3DZvD0vDIGbg4%26key%3Dyt6%26expire%3D1446006686%26id%3Do-AGEefyrMjFpQIEpOLLg1rou7FbLBDGNGJrmNWIfzK_YJ%26ms%3Dau%26mt%3D1445984927%26mv%3Dm%26mm%3D31%26source%3Dyoutube%26pl%3D20%26mn%3Dsn-xguxaxjvh-31oe%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%26ip%3D92.255.195.69%26fexp%3D9405982%252C9407745%252C9408710%252C9414764%252C9415521%252C9416126%252C9416916%252C9417224%252C9417707%252C9418204%252C9418997%252C9419354%252C9419444%252C9419745%252C9420540%252C9422339%252C9422431%252C9423306%26sparams%3Dclen%252Ccwbhb%252Cdur%252Cgir%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Ckeepalive%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpl%252Csource%252Cupn%252Cexpire%26lmt%3D1441184970413183%26gir%3Dyes,size=1280x720\u0026index=711-1702\u0026projection_type=1\u0026fps=24\u0026bitrate=2204323\u0026clen=56270760\u0026type=video%2Fmp4%3B+codecs%3D%22avc1.4d401f%22\u0026init=0-710\u0026itag=136\u0026quality_label=720p\u0026lmt=1441186483538674\u0026url=http%3A%2F%2Fr1---sn-xguxaxjvh-31oe.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fsver%3D3%26dur%3D422.374%26signature%3D05F2CE5DF7C4B748A7251CEC93897FF6DE2C855A.98FED6AA039B11C0E13ADDA3039933F3A0EE09F3%26initcwndbps%3D3415000%26cwbhb%3Dyes%26keepalive%3Dyes%26clen%3D56270760%26itag%3D136%26ipbits%3D0%26upn%3DZvD0vDIGbg4%26key%3Dyt6%26expire%3D1446006686%26id%3Do-AGEefyrMjFpQIEpOLLg1rou7FbLBDGNGJrmNWIfzK_YJ%26ms%3Dau%26mt%3D1445984927%26mv%3Dm%26mm%3D31%26source%3Dyoutube%26pl%3D20%26mn%3Dsn-xguxaxjvh-31oe%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%26ip%3D92.255.195.69%26fexp%3D9405982%252C9407745%252C9408710%252C9414764%252C9415521%252C9416126%252C9416916%252C9417224%252C9417707%252C9418204%252C9418997%252C9419354%252C9419444%252C9419745%252C9420540%252C9422339%252C9422431%252C9423306%26sparams%3Dclen%252Ccwbhb%252Cdur%252Cgir%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Ckeepalive%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpl%252Csource%252Cupn%252Cexpire%26lmt%3D1441186483538674%26gir%3Dyes,size=854x480\u0026index=710-1701\u0026projection_type=1\u0026fps=24\u0026bitrate=1102634\u0026clen=29117072\u0026type=video%2Fmp4%3B+codecs%3D%22avc1.4d401e%22\u0026init=0-709\u0026itag=135\u0026quality_label=480p\u0026lmt=1441186509439925\u0026url=http%3A%2F%2Fr1---sn-xguxaxjvh-31oe.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fsver%3D3%26dur%3D422.374%26signature%3D5401F32C6479356A59C57A804EB6125B5BF6774B.CBD2FEEC8BB094552CC44FBB6E0020F59604A196%26initcwndbps%3D3415000%26cwbhb%3Dyes%26keepalive%3Dyes%26clen%3D29117072%26itag%3D135%26ipbits%3D0%26upn%3DZvD0vDIGbg4%26key%3Dyt6%26expire%3D1446006686%26id%3Do-AGEefyrMjFpQIEpOLLg1rou7FbLBDGNGJrmNWIfzK_YJ%26ms%3Dau%26mt%3D1445984927%26mv%3Dm%26mm%3D31%26source%3Dyoutube%26pl%3D20%26mn%3Dsn-xguxaxjvh-31oe%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%26ip%3D92.255.195.69%26fexp%3D9405982%252C9407745%252C9408710%252C9414764%252C9415521%252C9416126%252C9416916%252C9417224%252C9417707%252C9418204%252C9418997%252C9419354%252C9419444%252C9419745%252C9420540%252C9422339%252C9422431%252C9423306%26sparams%3Dclen%252Ccwbhb%252Cdur%252Cgir%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Ckeepalive%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpl%252Csource%252Cupn%252Cexpire%26lmt%3D1441186509439925%26gir%3Dyes,size=640x360\u0026index=710-1701\u0026projection_type=1\u0026fps=24\u0026bitrate=602389\u0026clen=14677870\u0026type=video%2Fmp4%3B+codecs%3D%22avc1.4d401e%22\u0026init=0-709\u0026itag=134\u0026quality_label=360p\u0026lmt=1441186480705375\u0026url=http%3A%2F%2Fr1---sn-xguxaxjvh-31oe.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fsver%3D3%26dur%3D422.374%26signature%3DE3C1420821F980DD7CDBE902A076D985EEB1C654.ABB9F68163945DDF071A693C3370C50A80590AF2%26initcwndbps%3D3415000%26cwbhb%3Dyes%26keepalive%3Dyes%26clen%3D14677870%26itag%3D134%26ipbits%3D0%26upn%3DZvD0vDIGbg4%26key%3Dyt6%26expire%3D1446006686%26id%3Do-AGEefyrMjFpQIEpOLLg1rou7FbLBDGNGJrmNWIfzK_YJ%26ms%3Dau%26mt%3D1445984927%26mv%3Dm%26mm%3D31%26source%3Dyoutube%26pl%3D20%26mn%3Dsn-xguxaxjvh-31oe%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%26ip%3D92.255.195.69%26fexp%3D9405982%252C9407745%252C9408710%252C9414764%252C9415521%252C9416126%252C9416916%252C9417224%252C9417707%252C9418204%252C9418997%252C9419354%252C9419444%252C9419745%252C9420540%252C9422339%252C9422431%252C9423306%26sparams%3Dclen%252Ccwbhb%252Cdur%252Cgir%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Ckeepalive%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpl%252Csource%252Cupn%252Cexpire%26lmt%3D1441186480705375%26gir%3Dyes,size=426x240\u0026index=675-1666\u0026projection_type=1\u0026fps=24\u0026bitrate=251001\u0026clen=12613725\u0026type=video%2Fmp4%3B+codecs%3D%22avc1.4d4015%22\u0026init=0-674\u0026itag=133\u0026quality_label=240p\u0026lmt=1441186480845046\u0026url=http%3A%2F%2Fr1---sn-xguxaxjvh-31oe.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fsver%3D3%26dur%3D422.374%26signature%3D8774AC3FE7CCA6A0F5F12B3DF43F53ACB173DFCA.9AF21A49D41E6FC620C3113405AE218CE8FF68EE%26initcwndbps%3D3415000%26cwbhb%3Dyes%26keepalive%3Dyes%26clen%3D12613725%26itag%3D133%26ipbits%3D0%26upn%3DZvD0vDIGbg4%26key%3Dyt6%26expire%3D1446006686%26id%3Do-AGEefyrMjFpQIEpOLLg1rou7FbLBDGNGJrmNWIfzK_YJ%26ms%3Dau%26mt%3D1445984927%26mv%3Dm%26mm%3D31%26source%3Dyoutube%26pl%3D20%26mn%3Dsn-xguxaxjvh-31oe%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%26ip%3D92.255.195.69%26fexp%3D9405982%252C9407745%252C9408710%252C9414764%252C9415521%252C9416126%252C9416916%252C9417224%252C9417707%252C9418204%252C9418997%252C9419354%252C9419444%252C9419745%252C9420540%252C9422339%252C9422431%252C9423306%26sparams%3Dclen%252Ccwbhb%252Cdur%252Cgir%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Ckeepalive%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpl%252Csource%252Cupn%252Cexpire%26lmt%3D1441186480845046%26gir%3Dyes,size=256x144\u0026index=672-1663\u0026projection_type=1\u0026fps=12\u0026bitrate=109395\u0026clen=5612068\u0026type=video%2Fmp4%3B+codecs%3D%22avc1.4d400c%22\u0026init=0-671\u0026itag=160\u0026quality_label=144p\u0026lmt=1441186480946934\u0026url=http%3A%2F%2Fr1---sn-xguxaxjvh-31oe.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fsver%3D3%26dur%3D422.416%26signature%3D1E28FB3D38E8B6E460EE30809AE341CB42C80C87.0A1BA4B4018A51A8DD01864DC8B3C8A42F14A40E%26initcwndbps%3D3415000%26cwbhb%3Dyes%26keepalive%3Dyes%26clen%3D5612068%26itag%3D160%26ipbits%3D0%26upn%3DZvD0vDIGbg4%26key%3Dyt6%26expire%3D1446006686%26id%3Do-AGEefyrMjFpQIEpOLLg1rou7FbLBDGNGJrmNWIfzK_YJ%26ms%3Dau%26mt%3D1445984927%26mv%3Dm%26mm%3D31%26source%3Dyoutube%26pl%3D20%26mn%3Dsn-xguxaxjvh-31oe%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%26ip%3D92.255.195.69%26fexp%3D9405982%252C9407745%252C9408710%252C9414764%252C9415521%252C9416126%252C9416916%252C9417224%252C9417707%252C9418204%252C9418997%252C9419354%252C9419444%252C9419745%252C9420540%252C9422339%252C9422431%252C9423306%26sparams%3Dclen%252Ccwbhb%252Cdur%252Cgir%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Ckeepalive%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpl%252Csource%252Cupn%252Cexpire%26lmt%3D1441186480946934%26gir%3Dyes,bitrate=128209\u0026lmt=1441184480063832\u0026index=592-1139\u0026clen=6711016\u0026init=0-591\u0026projection_type=1\u0026type=audio%2Fmp4%3B+codecs%3D%22mp4a.40.2%22\u0026url=http%3A%2F%2Fr1---sn-xguxaxjvh-31oe.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fsver%3D3%26dur%3D422.510%26signature%3D7042D94BCCB4BA3EA2FB86CBD939A96935A90B8D.9AD051D5E30D8244D377A2FEAD86F70A5C879872%26initcwndbps%3D3415000%26cwbhb%3Dyes%26keepalive%3Dyes%26clen%3D6711016%26itag%3D140%26ipbits%3D0%26upn%3DZvD0vDIGbg4%26key%3Dyt6%26expire%3D1446006686%26id%3Do-AGEefyrMjFpQIEpOLLg1rou7FbLBDGNGJrmNWIfzK_YJ%26ms%3Dau%26mt%3D1445984927%26mv%3Dm%26mm%3D31%26source%3Dyoutube%26pl%3D20%26mn%3Dsn-xguxaxjvh-31oe%26mime%3Daudio%252Fmp4%26ip%3D92.255.195.69%26fexp%3D9405982%252C9407745%252C9408710%252C9414764%252C9415521%252C9416126%252C9416916%252C9417224%252C9417707%252C9418204%252C9418997%252C9419354%252C9419444%252C9419745%252C9420540%252C9422339%252C9422431%252C9423306%26sparams%3Dclen%252Ccwbhb%252Cdur%252Cgir%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Ckeepalive%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpl%252Csource%252Cupn%252Cexpire%26lmt%3D1441184480063832%26gir%3Dyes\u0026itag=140" ...`

Этот код должен наводить вас на мысль, как извлечь данные. Если не наводит, то вам рано этим заниматься, просто воспользуйтесь готовым решением и не изобретайте велосипед.